# Is it possible to adjust the height of a container to the height of its child element that has position absolute?

Tags: javascript, css, layout

I have a web page with a search field in it, like so:

[image]

When the user starts typing in the search field, the autocomplete list will appear. To prevent it from ruining the layout of the page, it has the `position` attribute set to `absolute`. The trouble is, when there is little content on the page and when the screen size is rather small, the autocomplete list will spread down below the bottom border of the `html` element (and therefore below the footer), like so:

[image]

I understand that the whole purpose of `position: absolute` is to make an element independent of the flow of other elements, but is there a way to adjust the height of the container element to the height of its child element that has `position: absolute` using CSS? If not, what other technique would you recommend?

Comment: if your parent has position: relative and overflow: hidden or auto, then you should see a scroll bar

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: is the list only goes behind the footer, or it also exceeds the height of you html?

Comment: @Eeilya: on some pages, it exceeds the height of html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

footer height: 60px;

footer div id="footer";

background behind footer as the window (instead of it all being inside a specific division);

If you have JQuery:

```
//Replace 120 below with the height of your footer + padding + how far the search bar is from the top of your screen
var height = ($(window).height() - 120); 
$('#footer').css({"height", height});
```

make it look a bit better by replacing the above adjustment with...

```
$('#footer').stop().animate({height: height});
```

Comment: Yes, it feels there's no other way but to go down the JavaScript road. I will play with your solution and report back.

Comment: Javascript's syntax may look intimidating at first but I assure you that with practice it will feel just as easy to use as HTML and CSS :) You are welcome to contact me at any time if you need any help :)

Comment: It's not that I am unfamiliar with JavaScript, it's just that I thought pure CSS could offer an elegant solution. Right now though I am puzzled by the fact that the height of my window object (`$(window).height()`) is the same as the height of the `html` element (both are 567px), but smaller than the height of the autocomplete area (627px). How could that be and what object will contain the actual height of the whole contents of the page? Could it be `scrollHeight`or something?

Comment: Ah, that's more like it: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollHeight` (= 927px)

Comment: @azangru as far as I am aware, $(document).height() will return the height of the entire HTML document, whereas $(window).height() returns the height of what is currently visible on the page. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean *behind the footer*.

If so, you can use css [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property to bring your autocomplete list in front of the footer element.

Comment: I mean, the autocomplete area is allowed to be no taller that the upper border of the footer. It should not overlap with the footer. It should either push the footer down somehow (which isn't going to happen I am afraid) or push the lower border of html (or body) down.

Answer (score 0):

For this using
Overflow-y:scroll
max-height:200px
position:absolute
z-index:2

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.autocomplete-list {
     margin-bottom: [height of footer]
}
```

If the list exceeds the height of your body, then there is something wrong with your css.

The above css wont let anything goes outside the body and if it does, then you will get and scroll bar.

And the `margin-bottom` of the autocomplete-list keeps it above the footer